# Counting number of labels created per day in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, statistics

I receive many enquiries/emails every day. Each one is labeled as enquiry. Each enquiry/email is responded to within the specific thread. Some email threads can include 20 or more emails and each email in the thread is tagged "inquiry". Therefore the enquiry label (as a count) gets inflated.

I am looking to find the number of enquiry (labels) emails I receive per day
for a given time period. Obviously I only want one count for each enquiry-email and I don't want to include the (inflated) response emails in the thread.

Is this possible? And can you assist me to set this up?

Comment: Google script? I wouldn't know where to start myself, but you could probably write a script and get statistics in a spreadsheet on Google Docs.

Comment: Google created a tool http://gmailmeter.com/ but it is limited and does not count Labels.

Comment: Looks like an interesting tool. It it NOT an official tool though, not made by Google (though it runs on Google's servers).